# Using SFML in Eclipse (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, sfml, nvcc

I'm trying to get SFML (www.sfml-dev.org) running under Eclipse which is running on Ubuntu 16.04, my c++ compiler is nvcc as this is a cuda project. I have my includes and libraries set up as follows:

[image]

[image]

The project builds fine, but when I run it I get the error message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-window.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is weird, because the file exists (/home/timo/cuda-workspace/CudaTutorial/SFML/lib). Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Try use `ldconfig` to folder with library.

Comment: Or set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/timo/cuda-workspace/CudaTutorial/SFML/lib` before running the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end creating a conf file did it:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/sfml.conf
/lib/SFML/lib
sudo ldconfig
```

(I put the SFML build into lib in case I want to use it in another project).